# Dependency validation in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: validation, visual-studio-2015, architecture, dependencies

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2015, with three assemblies (X, Y and Z).
X is depended of Y and Z as is uses them both.

I want to be sure that no developer is creating a reference from Y to Z.
It looks like the only option I have is to create a Layer Diagram and set namespace Z as "Forbidden Namespaces" in layer Y. But I can still create the reference so Y is depended of Z, as I will first get validation error when I from Y tries to use an object in Z.

Are there any possible solution to get validation check for just having illegal dependency? I.e. if I create a reference from Y to Z.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use the tool NDepend that lets write code rule over [C# LINQ queries](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL).

To forbid assembly Y to use assembly Z the rule could look like:

```
warnif count > 0 
from a in Application.Assemblies where 
  a.IsUsing("Z".MatchAssembly()) &&
  a.Name == @"Y"
select a
```

Actually such rule can be generated in a single click from the [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph) or from the [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm):

[image: NDepend genrate dependency rule]

Comment: I have looked into ndepend and also consider that as an alternative if VS can't fullfill the needs. But I would prefer Vs as we already have it and together with the live validation released in Preview 5 it could be very cool.

Comment: Have tried NDepend and actually if I use your example it have same functionality as VS. So I can add a reference and also a using of a namespace from the "Z" assembly, but I will still not have the warning before I try to use some from the namespace.

Comment: Subtle difference indeed, the compiler will discard this useless using namespace, and since NDepend will gather dependencies from compiled code, it won't notice this.